# Create a new variable from each iteration of a for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function the takes two strings: one is the "genome" of a bacteria, for example ATACGAGA or something like that.  The other string is a sequence of DNA, such as ATA that has to be found within the genome.  The function is supposed to return the best similarity score that it finds when it compares the sequence of DNA to the genome.  So, since ATA is 3 characters, it would compare ATA to the first three characters in the genome, and then the second, third and fourth characters, then the third, fourth and fifth characters, and so on.  Since ATA are the first three characters of the genome, the similarity score would be 1.  If the substring I was looking for was ATG, for example, since 2/3 of the characters are the same, it would return 0.66.

So far, my function returns accurately the simScore of each iteration of the first for loop.  For example, if the genome string was ABCABC and the substring was ABC, it accurately calculates the simScore at i=0 as 1 and i=3 as 1 because ABC perfectly matches with the genome at those positions.  However, to find the best simScore, I need to somehow find the simScore of every iteration of the for loop, and either:
1. Compare it to the previous simScore each iteration and always keep the higher simScore, or
2: store each new simScore in a new variable and then compare all of the simScores to determine the highest one.

```cpp
double findBestSimScore(string genome, string sequence)
{
    double simScore; // similarity score for the genome and the substring
    double newSimScore;
    double bestSimScore;
    int differences = 0;

    if(genome == "" || sequence == "")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(genome.length() < sequence.length())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < genome.length(); i++)
        {
            string sub = genome.substr(i, sequence.length()); 
            differences = 0;


            for(int c = 0; c < sequence.length(); c++)
            {
                if(sub[c] != sequence[c])
                {
                    differences++;
                }
            }

            simScore = (sequence.length() - differences) / (sequence.length() * 1.0); // This calculation needs to be done in each iteration of the first for loop and stored as a new variable, or 
                                                                                      // It could also work if each time the simScore is calculated, it is compared to the previous simScore to see if it is larger
        }

        /*
        Need if else statements here that compare each simsScore and determine the highest simScore
        */

        return bestSimScore;
    }
}

int main()
{

    //test 1 
    //
    cout << findBestSimScore("ABCABC", "ABT") << endl;
```

Comment: The shown code does not compile, for obvious reasons. Also you are aware of arrays, so I really do not understand what your question is. Please ask one.

Comment: What about a genome "ABCABD" and a sequence "BDE"? Should that say "0.666.."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with a move of the sequence through the genome starting at a negative position (had an invalid index in the original code). The best score is exchanged (that was your question) if a better was found `bestSimScore = newSimScore > bestSimScore ? newSimScore : bestSimScore;` (storing in an array is much more complicated). The loop can be stopped with a `1.0`score:

```
double findBestSimScore(string genome, string sequence)
{

  if (genome == "" || sequence == "")
  {
    return 0;
  }

  double bestSimScore = 0;
  // move virtually the sequence string through the genome starting at a negative position! 
  for (int i = -(int)sequence.length() + 1; i < (int)genome.length(); i++)
  {
    int matchCount = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < sequence.length(); j++)
    {
      int genomeIndex = i + j;
      if (genomeIndex >= 0 && genomeIndex < genome.length()) // do not check if positions are out of range ()
      {
        matchCount += genome[genomeIndex] == sequence[j] ? 1 : 0;
      }
    }
    // calculate new score and compare to previous
    double newSimScore = (double)matchCount / (double)sequence.length();
    bestSimScore = newSimScore > bestSimScore ? newSimScore : bestSimScore;

    if (bestSimScore == 1.0) // if we found a full match: we can stop 
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  return bestSimScore;
}

int main()
{
  assert(findBestSimScore("ABCABC", "ABT") == 2.0 / 3.0);
  assert(findBestSimScore("ABCABC", "ABC") == 1.0);
  assert(findBestSimScore("ABCABC", "BC") == 1.0);
  assert(findBestSimScore("ABCABC", "ABCABC") == 1.0);
  assert(findBestSimScore("ABCABD", "BDE") == 2.0 / 3.0);
  assert(findBestSimScore("BDE", "ABCABD") == 1.0 / 3.0);
  return 0;
}
```